# What's the point of Netgear's WNHDB3004 "3DHD WIRELESS HOME THEATER NETWORKING KIT"

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Here's a crude representation of what I've got at home:

```
floor 2     INTERNETS ---- MODEM/ROUTER ---- MY COMPUTER
                                |
floor 1                   WIFI REPEATER ---- stuff
                                |
floor 0                    more stuff        TELEVISION
```

Now, as part of our sat tv subscription we can get an [additional service](http://www.sky.it/offerta-sky/decoder-hd/sky-on-demand.html) if we connect our decoder (located by `TELEVISION` obviously) to the internet. What they suggest is buying a [Netgear *3DHD* WIRELESS **HOME THEATER** ***NETWORKING KIT***](http://www.netgear.com/3DHD) This seems incredibly suspicious.

1. What does this thing actually do that our existing wireless-enabled routers doesn't do?
2. What's the point of having a *third* wifi router in the same house, this time only for one television?
3. If I do decide to plunge €99 for this, should I connect it to the **WiFi repeater** (which does *not* provide AAA quality internet, at least for all gaming purposes) or to my **modem/router** (risking issues with low signal?).

Answer (score 1):

I will make this answer short.

I see a couple things your typical $150-200 router does not have.

The first is the following:

> 802.11i (WPA/ WPA2–PSK ), 802.11d, 802.11e (WMM), 802.11h

I would have to look up what standards these are exactly but these are not supported by your typical home router.

The second thing I noticed was this:

> Superior WiFi video reliability using advanced technologies  Transmit
>   beamforming Space-time block coding (STBC) Channel state aware WiFi
>   link management using real time spectrum analysis

Of course this also might be a glorified QOS.

While 300 Mbps is actually one of the slowest rates Netgear sells the 4x4 radio actually makes it decent.

> Wireless: 802.11a/n 4x4 access point or bridge - auto rate capable up 300 Mbps

Of course the Netgear R6300-100NAS AC1750 802.11 which is only an extra $50 has 4x that and supports 802.11ac.  In the end this is a fancy repeater, they are $50-60 routers being sold two to a kit.

I don't know how faster your current repeater is, I can tell you that this would replace your current one, and it likely would be faster then your current one.  Of course I would not purchase any ranger extender that didn't match my current router.

Comment: How can it replace my repeater? The graphic clearly shows it needs to have a _wired_ connection to my router.

Comment: It has ethernet ports on the back of it. Click product specs on the same webpage you just linked

Comment: @badp - The product you link to is 2 repeaters basically.  Look at the diagram they provided.  Like I said it sounds like you should just purchase another repeater ( same model as you already have ).

Answer (score 0):

Its just marketing jargon. "Wireless home theater networking kit" translates to wireless bridge in Network engineer speech.

This review actually clarifies things a bit

http://www.anandtech.com/show/4152/netgear-3dhd-wireless-home-theatre-networking-kit